# Recorrer array y guardarlo en una base de datos

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo lo siguiente para obtener los datos por medio de la api, lo cual recorro para mostrar la info que necesito la cual me funciona correctamente.

Ahora lo que quiero es guardar esta info en una base de datos por medio de Mysql, se que debo crear una consulta con "INSERT INTO" y especificar los valores. Previamente realizando la conexion a la base de datos.

lo que va mi consulta es como saco la info de cada foreach para colocarla dentro de la consulta Mysql, ya que si llamo la variables fuera del foreach no me trae todos lo datos.

```
$headers = [
  "credentials"
];

$ch = curl_init("/api/orders");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$data = json_decode($response,true);

foreach ($data['list'] as $repository){
        $datos = $repository["orderId"];

        $idOrder = $datos;

        $ch1 = curl_init("https:www/orders/".$idOrder);
        curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $response1 = curl_exec($ch1);
        curl_close($ch1);
        $data2 = json_decode($response1,true);

        $array = array($data2); 

        foreach ($array as $repository2){
            echo "<div>";
            echo "<p>";
            echo $repository2['orderId']; 
            echo "</p>";

            $dataOrden = $repository2['items'];
            foreach ($dataOrden as $items){
                echo "<p>";
                echo $items['name'];
                echo "</p>";
                echo "<p>";
                echo $items['price'];
                echo "</p>";
            }

            $datashiping = $repository2['shippingData']['address'];
            echo "<p>";
            echo $datashiping['city'];
            echo "</p>";
            echo "<p>";
            echo $datashiping['street'];
            echo "</p>";
            echo "</div>";
        }

    }
```

Comment: Para el INSERT hay varias posibilidades. Una es escribir una consulta preparada e irla ejecutando en cada iteracción del bucle. La otra es hacerlo desde una transacción (pero este depende del engine de tu base de datos). Otro aspecto a considerar es la seguridad, para evitar *inyección SQL*. Lo que sí es extraño es que ejecutes peticiones cURL en un bucle ¿? Si es posible, trae todos los datos en una sola petición. Este tipo de operaciones son asíncronas, y si vas a hacer varias, deberías usar [`curl_multi_init()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.curl-multi-init.php).

Comment: la tengo dentro del foreach ya que como estoy haciendo 2 peticiones 1 para traer la lista de ordenes la recorro para obtener la id y con esa id la 2 para traer los detalles de cada orden.

Comment: ¿La API la has programado tú o es una API de terceros? Si la has programado tú, lo propio sería crear un tipo de petición que te traiga una lista de órdenes por un ID, si es una API de terceros, puede que cuente ya con este tipo de petición, lo cual es habitual. Lo que no es habitual es tener que enviar la petición `N` veces para obtener `N` elementos. Eso sería algo así como mandar un pedido de 1,000 naranjas cada una en un vehículo diferente. ¿Tendría sentido hacer tal cosa? ¿No es mejor mandar todas las naranjas en un solo camión?